# Tensorflow.js data formatting/reshape

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I have about 1397 sample data in a `txt` file:

```
(x, y)
907 1 < first point (x,y)
907 1 < second point 
908 3
910 4
911 6
913 8
914 10
916 12
917 13
919 15
920 17
922 18 ...
...
```

I want to get the first 16 point, and my 17th point as the output prediction data for those 16 points, and so on...

For example, I want the first 16 points, and the next point is the output data. And, I want to continue doing it for the next 1000 sample points.

How should I format them in Tensorflow.js?

tldr: I have 1000+ sample data, (x,y) points in a .txt file. I want to get first 16 point as my input, and the next point as my prediction, and I want to do it for the next 1000 point. How should I format them in tensorflowjs?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Import the data
2. Parse it into an array of objects
3. Prepare the data for your model

**1. Import the data**

As there is no information on if you are working in browser or nodejs, I will skip the details but goes along the lines of

- Browser: `fetch("url/to/text/file.txt")`
- NodeJS: `readFileSync("path/to/file.text")`

**2. Parse the data**

Once you imported your data into, for example, a variable called `text`

```js
const originalText = ... // However you get your data

const dataPoints = originalText
                       .split("\n") // returns an array where each line is a value
                       .map(line => {
                           return line.split(" ") // returns an array where 0 is the x and 1 is the y
                       })
```

**3. Prepare the data**

```
const history = 16 // You said you wanted 16 previous points of data, 
let xs = []
let ys = []


for (let i = history; i < dataPoints.length; i++){
    let currentY = dataPoints[i][1]  // "i" is current point, "1" is because y is at position 1 in the array
    let currentXs = []
    // Loop back to previous data points to get all the Xs you want
    for(let j = history - 1; i >= 0; i==){
        currentXs.push(dataPoints[j][0]) // "0" because x is at position 0 in the array
    }
    xs.push(currentXs)
    ys.push(currentY)
}
```